# Go correct behaviour, or compiler bug?

Tags: go

```
package main

type Key struct {
    stuff1 string
    stuff2 []string
}

type Val struct {
}

type MyMap struct {
    map1 map[Key]*Val // compiles fine!
}

func main() {
    var map2 map[Key]*Val // "invalid map key type Key"
}
```

Is this the correct behaviour, or a bug in go compiler?

I am using go-1.1 on Linux x64.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=5698 is the relevant bug in case anyone wants to follow along.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is right. From the specs: [Map Types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types):

> The comparison operators == and != must be fully defined for operands of the key type; thus the key type must not be a function, map, or slice.

This restriction applies transitively if the key type is a struct to all of the struct fields, they must obey the above quoted rule as well, which

```
stuff2 []string
```

does not.

EDIT:

What concerns `map1` not being flagged, that probably *is* a bug, perhaps caused by MyMap never being referenced and thus it's type checking was probably skipped.

Comment: @HowardGuo Consider filing a bug.

Comment: @HowardGuo: Please see the updated answer. I'll check if it is a known issue and report it if not.